# Is it possible to receive subclass's name in compile time in Java?

Tags: java, class, inheritance, static, abstract-class

I'm trying to create a snacks machine implementation in java.
I have created an abstract class named `Product` that will give the basic design for each of the offered products.

I mean we have the `abstract class Product` and then other classes like `Nachos`, `Cake`, etc.. that inherita from `Product`.

`Product` class does not contain too much, it just contains the `name` , the `price` and the `available amount` of the product (these are the fields in the class).

It also has `get` methods for the fields that just return the value for each one.

The problem is that I want to set the `name` of the product as a `static final` because if a product's name is `Nachos`, it won't be changed. I mean it'll be possible to create more `Nachos` objects but the name of their class is still going to be `Nachos`.

So there is no reason to NOT to do that `static final`.

The issue with that is that i'm not sure how to set it correctly.

```
public abstract class Product {
    
    private static final String productName = getClass().getSimpleName();
    private int price;
    private int amount;

....
Constructor..

Get methods..
```

I thought about `getClass().getName()` or `getSimpleName()` but it gives me an IDE error which indicates that the only way for me to also use that field as `static final` and also to use `getClass` is by writing `Product.class.getName();`.

The problem is that if i'll do that, the name that will be returned is `Product` and not `Cake` or `Nachos` or other sub classes.

Comment: I highly discourage the approach of coupling the value returned by the getter to the name of the class. --- Why don't you write `getClass().getSimpleName();` in the getter? Or even better: remove the field, make the getter abstract, let the child classes implement them.

Comment: @Turing85 I understand your point, but why not to make this field `static`? I mean, the name of the class will be the same for each object of that class, so each object of `Nachos`, will be needed to run `getClass().SgetSimpleName();` instead of already having it.

Comment: You are overthinking it. For one, if we were to write `return "Nachos"` in a getter, this will always be the exact same `String` (`"Nachos" == "Nachos"` will always evaluate to `true`).  For another, even if we were to write `getClass().getSimpleName()`: call it often enough, and the JVM will hot-compile and optimize the code. --- ["*premature optimization is the root of all evil*" -- Donald Ervin Knuth: *Computer Programming as an Art* (1974), p. 671](https://dl.acm.org/ft_gateway.cfm?id=361612&ftid=289767)

Comment: Thanks for your answers. But is it possible to do it in the way that I tried? with a `static final` as the field and optimize it so every subclass will automatically have his own name without the need to run `getClass()` ?

Comment: If you have a `static final String` field in the `Product` class it can reference only one string (i.e. the name of one class). It can't be "Nachos" for the `Nachos` class and "Cake" for the `Cake` class because it is only one field for `Product` and all its subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

If your Class has some attribute that describes that Class (e.g a product name), that's an attribute of that Class. You shouldn't write code that uses the name of the class itself with getClass().getName(), that's tying your business logic to implementation details, and there's no reason (or very few good reasons), why your code would need to know the name of the class itself.

Instead, add an attribute like productName to your class:

```
public class Product{

    private String productName;

    public Product(String name){
        this.productName = name;
    }

    public String getProductName(){
        return this.productName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just use "final" and drop the "static". By declaring the variable as final you can assign the value of "getClass" that use "this" for reference. "this" doesn't work for static.

```
abstract class Product {
    private final String productName = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }
}
```

The "this" can be omitted in "this.getClass().getSimpleName()", leaving only "getClass().getSimpleName().

It doesn't make sense to use "static" because you would access the attribute directly via the class reference. But this would not work because to get the "getClass" you would need to be within some scope (constructor...) because the attribute is static, it is impossible to assign the value of the attribute at the time of its creation, making it impossible to use the " Final".

Answer (score 0):

A static member belongs to the class in which it is defined.  Declaring `productName` as static on the class `Product` means that every concrete implementation would have the same value.   This is not what you want.

I think the solution that is closest to what you describe is not to have a member at all.  Instead, declare an accessor as follows.

```
public abstract class Product {
  public final String getProductName() {
    return getClass().getSimpleName();
  }
}
```

Thus, every instance of a given subclass (e.g. `Taco`) references the same `Class` object for its type.  We never duplicate the value because we are accessing the singular value in our memory space.  We declare this method to be final so that subclasses cannot override it.  This enforces that the `productName` will always be the `simpleName` of the concrete implementation.